# For loop not working with int

Tags: java

Alright so I had my for loop before set up like...

```
for(int i=0; i<inventory.size(); i++){
    g.drawImage(
        inventory.get(i).getImage(),
        Game.WIDTH - inventory.get(i).getImage().getWidth() - 2, 
        (Game.HEIGHT / 2 - hud.getSideHeight() / 2) + (i*4+2) + i*(inventory.get(i).getImage().getWidth()),
        inventory.get(i).width, 
        inventory.get(i).height, 
        null
    );
}
```

But now instead of it running till inventory.size() I want it to run till it reaches seven so I did this...

```
for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
    g.drawImage(
        inventory.get(i).getImage(),
        Game.WIDTH - inventory.get(i).getImage().getWidth() - 2, 
        (Game.HEIGHT / 2 - hud.getSideHeight() / 2) + (i*4+2) + i*(inventory.get(i).getImage().getWidth()),
        inventory.get(i).width, 
        inventory.get(i).height, 
        null
    );
}
```

Why doesn't this work? I am getting the java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException error. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Your inventory does not contain 7 elements.

Answer (score 1):

what happens if there is not 7 in the list?

try

```
for(int i=0; i<inventory.size() && i < 7; i++){
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your requirement is to loop up to 7 maximum. Modify the for loop like this for it:

```
for(int i=0; i<Math.min(inventory.size(),7); i++){
```

Math.min() will take the smallest argument of the 2. So if the collection is less than 7, it will loop up to the size of the collection. If the collection is more than 7, it will loop to 7.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code :

```
int temp=inventory.size();
if(temp>7){
  temp=7;
}
for(int i=0; i<temp; i++){
    g.drawImage(
        inventory.get(i).getImage(),
        Game.WIDTH - inventory.get(i).getImage().getWidth() - 2, 
        (Game.HEIGHT / 2 - hud.getSideHeight() / 2) + (i*4+2) + i*(inventory.get(i).getImage().getWidth()),
        inventory.get(i).width, 
        inventory.get(i).height, 
        null
    );
}
```

also check for null condition for inventory list